# SQLITE database locked during transaction

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, transactions, locked

I have been trying to figure this out for days now but I cannot figure out what is going on. In my app I want to be able to delete an item, and related items from a tableView. So when the delete button in the TableView is pushed the following method is called.

```
- (BOOL) deleteDuik:(MOODuik *) duik
{
    int diveid = [duik duikId];
    NSLog(@"Begin Delete");
    sqlite3 *db = [self openDatabase];

    sqlite3_stmt * deleteStmt = nil;


    BOOL succes = TRUE;

    @try{
        if (db != NULL) {
            sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);

            //NSString *sqlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from duik where duikid = %d", diveid];

            const char *sql = "delete from duik where duikid = ?";
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &deleteStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {

                sqlite3_bind_int(deleteStmt, 1, diveid);

                sqlite3_step(deleteStmt);
                sqlite3_finalize(deleteStmt);

                deleteStmt = nil;

                sql = "delete from waarneming where duikid = ?";

                if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &deleteStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    sqlite3_bind_int(deleteStmt, 1, diveid);

                    sqlite3_step(deleteStmt);
                    sqlite3_finalize(deleteStmt);
                }

            }

        } else
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to connect to db");
            succes = FALSE;
        }

        if(succes && ( [duik backendid] == 0 ||  [self deleteDuikServerSide:[duik backendid]]))
        {
            NSLog(@"End Delete");
            if(sqlite3_exec(db, "COMMIT TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0) !=SQLITE_OK) NSLog(@"SQL Error: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        } else{
            NSLog(@"Failed to delete remote copy");
            sqlite3_exec(db, "ROLLBACK TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);
            succes = false;
        }

    } @catch (NSException *e) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to delete: %@", [e description]);
        sqlite3_exec(db, "ROLLBACK TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);
    } @finally {

        @try {
            sqlite3_finalize(deleteStmt);
            sqlite3_close(db);

        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            //REally nothing to do here
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }

    return succes;
}
```

When I try to run this, it keeps telling me the database is locked, yet I have no idea why it is locked. I have checked to see if other actions require the DB at the same time but I cannot find any. Also, if I add a row from the same tableView, I use the same construction with a transaction and that one DOES work. I have tried everything I could come up with, rewritten this chunk of code at least 10 times but so far no luck.

Is there anyone who can tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: may be, any other class you forgot sqlite3_close(db);

Comment: Locked is only possible, if database is open.

Comment: try to remove sqlite3_close(db); after catch in finally block.

Comment: are you executing two sql statements in single transaction ?

Comment: @user968597 yes, I execute two statements in a single transaction. That is kind of the point of a transaction right?